# How to disable the BCC field in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, bcc

I want to disable the BCC field in Mozilla Thunderbird. I delete the BCC command in JS but it still working

> File Path :C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\distribution\extensions{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}\components
>
> File Name:calItipEmailTransport

Comment: You probably can't without studying and patching the source code of mozilla thunderbird. then recompile it. And socially, you should not: there are sometimes good reason to BCC.

Comment: My work nature requires to hide BCC .

Comment: I don't understand what "work nature" means. But if you really need to do that: 1. you'll need weeks (or perhaps months) of work (to study, improve the source code of thunderbird), and 2. remember people can use other mail agents (e.g. use some gmail account thru the web). I don't think it is worth spending months of work on that.

Comment: we have restricted users to use only thunderbird

Comment: So you are using social means (which is good) to forbid users to use anything else than thunderbird. Use the same social means to forbid BCC. Publish an internal rule forbidding BCC. Otherwise, ask your manager to allocate you several months of work to understand and patch thunderbird, and fork that [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project internally. I really think it is stupid to do so, but your manager could allocate resources on improving and patching thunderbird

Comment: Read much more about [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP). Your organization might add some filtering at the SMTP level

Comment: Are you aware that even if you remove BCC, the enduser could still resend the same email to another person? So what you want to do takes months of work, and is futile (because the enduser could still send "blindly" the same information). Again,think at the SMTP level, and understand what email is and the difference between [mail user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_client) and [mail transfer agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)

Comment: You are right..Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think this would be better done by your company outgoing mail server. However, I agree with @Basile - it seems that this is a case of using technology to force people to take a certain action, rather than developing a positive relationship between managers and staff and trusting them to respect the rules put in place. Ultimately, I personally prefer to work for firms that deliberately avoid authoritarian and top-down approaches to staff management, and any workplace that regards workers as a threat to be contained is suspect by default, in my book.